# Angular URLs (routes) customization with dynamic components

Tags: angular, firebase, routes, seo, server-side-rendering

I made an Angular project (e-commerce of motorbikes), and the component that shows product details is in charge of all products so the routing for this component is always the same:

```
https://fakeweb.com/second-hand-bikes/details?bikeId=7440483
```

This causes that all products have the same link for google (because google ignores parameters ?bikeId=.....)

My question is: **How I can customize urls depending on the fetched product ?**, like this:

```
https://fakeweb.com/second-hand-bikes/details/yamaha-xmax-300
```

I thought about doing one script that manually creates routes for every time a new product is added on the backend, but looks like a painful solution.

Any ideas? Thanks for any type of help!

Comment: Why not use your bikeId in the route?

Answer (score 0):

The route for the component that displays the details for a specific product would need a route parameter for the name of that product. We could implement this using the following Routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  [...]
  { path: 'second-hand-bikes/details/:name', component: ProductDetails }
];
```

The ProductDetails component must read the parameter, then load the product based on the name given in the parameter. The `ActivatedRoute` service provides a params `Observable` which we can subscribe to to get the route parameters:

```
productName: string;
private sub: any;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     this.productName = params['name'];

     // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```